# GWT view shrinks with browser resize

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

I am using GWT with GWT-Ext. I designed a simple panel with table and few buttons. In the browser all looks perfect. When I shrink the size of the browser my whole view also shrinks instead browser should show the vertical and horizontal scrollbars. Is there anything I can do here or this behavior is expected?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is dependent on your layout, which is just HTML in the end.

If you're using e.g. FlowPanel then the content will be resized. HorizontalPanel acts the same. On the other hand AbsolutePanel *should* give you pretty much static positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen even if you specify a width for your [SimplePanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html#methods_inherited_from_class_com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject) using the [setWidth(String width)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setWidth(java.lang.String)) method?

Comment: Oh yes I have tried that but it doesn't work. My html don't have any div tags only the empty body tags. I create a Panel and use new ViewPort(panel) and it shows up on browser.

Comment: What if you created an element in your html page with a specific size? I have a project in which I have a table of a specific size, and I load different panels into different cells. When I resize the browser window, the table stays the same width, and the scrollbars appear.

Comment: I tried by creating a html table with width and height. The table having just one row and one cell. I defined one div <div id="panel"/> in that cell. In the code I did this RootPanel.get("panel").add(topPanel); I get the scrollbars but the UI is not created but only a horizontal line, looks like everything is shrinked.